# urllib.parse Python2.7 equivalent

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, url, urllib, url-parsing

What is the Python2.7 equivalent to

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
```

I get

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Thanks!

Comment: You literally have not searched for "urlparse python2". Why?

Comment: @Tomalak Googled but didn't find parse_qs equivalent

Comment: When you Google "urlparse python2" it's the *first hit*. You may type use CTRL+F to find "parse_qs" on the documentation page. It's not that they have hidden that anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **[python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)** use

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
parsed_url = urlparse(url)
params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
```