# ImportError: No module named parse even after installing dataset and parse

Tags: python

I get the following error. I also installed PIP Parse and dataset using PIP install

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dataset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27amd64\lib\site-packages\dataset\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dataset.database import Database
  File "C:\Python27amd64\lib\site-packages\dataset\database.py", line 3, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Comment: How did you install using pip? Are you sure pip installed to the right version of python that you are trying to access? I would highly recommend using virtual environment

Comment: Can you show the code that caused this error? Specifically, line 1 of your code? It might be like scikit-learn where its package name is different from the library reference (i.e. "pip install scikit-learn" vs "import sklearn").  The documentation should tell you how to correctly reference it.

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback, I see that you use Python 2.7, however the code from the `dataset` package is using trying to import `urllib` as if was running Python 3, which is weird.

Ensure you have installed `dataset` properly using `pip` in the right Python version.

FYI : A fix if you want to edit the source code of `dataset` is to replace

```py
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
```

with

```py
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638366/urllib-parse-python2-7-equivalent)

To install `dataset` in the proper python version :

```
# If you have pip.exe in your PATH variable
pip install dataset

# If you have python3.exe in your PATH
python3 -m pip install dataset

# If you don't use the complete path to your python 3 installation
C:\Python3\python.exe -m pip install dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `python` command to install packages and run Python programs. For example: `python -m pip install dataset` and `python -c "import dataset; print('OK')"`.